# Правильное создания функции он-лайн

Tags: php

Ну вообщем , хочу с вами посоветоваться по поводу пользователей он-лайн в чате. Можно ли это сделать так:

1. Создаем столбик в таблице `users` под именем `online` (какого типа, хочу спросить у вас)
2. Дальше, если пользователь он-лайн то это 1, если же офф-лайн то 0
3. Потом выводим пользователя если он 1, таким способом:

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE online=1");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo "
   {$row['username']}"; }

*Можно ли это сделать так? Если же нет, то, пожалуйста, поправте.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю что это самый лучший способ, а если вдруг человек закроет браузер не нажав кнопку выйти, то он всегда будет онлайн. Лучше в базу заносить результат функции `time()` при входе, а потом запрос на подобии этого:

```
$time = time();
$online = $time - (20*60);                    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_come >= $online";
```

Comment: Так через 20 минут любой пользователь после входа окажется оффлайн. Это делается немного подругому, но логика почти такая-же.
Создаете колонку last_date, к примеру, в нее заносите дату каждого последнего обращения пользователя к сайту. А выводите список онлайн запрашивая и сравнивая время в этой колонке и текущее. Чем больше разница, тем большая вероятность, что человека нет онлайн. Но, в любом случае, без сессий и кукки не обойтись...

Answer (score 1):

Так все верно. Тип вы и сами определили (boolean).

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно, [`INT(1) или TINYINT(1)`](http://www.spravkaweb.ru/mysql/sql/vartype/)
2. Можно
3. Можно

   ```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE online=1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) echo $row['username'],"<br>";
   ```